# tinyMCE inline mode removes (replaces) <p> tag when erasing all content by highlighting text and pressing Delete or Backspace Key

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tinymce

I have tinyMCE inline mode set over a `<p>` tag. This `<p>` tag has an id, class and other attributes. When all the content of this `<p>` tag is erased at once by highlighting the text and pressing Delete or Backspace Key, the `<p>` tag is removed (and replaced) but the id, class and other attributes are gone. I have a temporary fix to disable these keys when the entire text is selected, but would like to have a better solution that allows users to use these keys while maintaining the original tag.

I created a config for inline mode, and I would expect that the `<p>` tag keep all its attributes even when the entire content is deleted at once. The `<p>` tag remains when the content is erased by deleting one character at a time, but not when the the entire text is selected and the Delete or Backspace key is pressed.

```html
<p id="pid" class="text-danger tinymce-body" data-original-text={{text}}>{{text}}</p>

var config = {
  selector: '.tinymce-body',
  menubar: false,
  inline: true,
  plugins: [
    'autoresize',
    'quickbars',
    'help'
  ],
  toolbar: false,
  newline_behaviour: 'linebreak',
};

tinymce.init(config);
```